# ng-table - how to merge columns under the same header?

Tags: angularjs, merge, header

I need to have a header above columns 'a+b', and, then, below this 1st header, a header for 'a' and another header for 'b'. Like this:

```
+-------------+---------------+
|   headerAB  |     HdrC      |
+-------------+               |
| HdrA | HdrB |               |
+-------------+---------------+
   a1    b1           c1 
   a2    b2           c2   
   a3    b3           c3 
   a4    b4           c4
```

**I also need to have the "filter=" and "sortable=" options active for cola and colb.**

I've searched a lot, with no success. NG-TABLE doesn't seem to provide a solution for this.

Can I nest 2 columns under a single header and still keep the filter and sortable options working perfectly?

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer for ng-table but believe ui-grid is a bit more active but still has limitations with regards to sub headers.  I've found in many cases I'm better off just using angular filters regular tables ng-repeat and my own paging with limitTo and startAt filters rather than relying on ngTable or ui-grid though.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid

https://github.com/esvit/ng-table
issue with options for ui grid 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/644

Comment: Thank you very much. I also believe that using the standard and reliable angular filters is the best way. I was led to believe that ng-table would provide a compreensive solution, but it doesn't, unfortunately.

Comment: No Problem.  ng-table is fine for the basic use case it was made to cover but anytime you get into trying to make a table or grid component things get hairy since there are so many various requirements around this type of textual data visualization it usually makes sense to just roll your own solution from basics.  The only major advantage with something like ui-grid is the virtual scrolling which comes in handy if you are trying to avoid paging and have lots of rows (much more efficient use of CPU and memory but you can do virtual scrolling yourself as well).

Comment: One other thing to note check out bindonce syntax since this can also help with reducing the number of persisted watchers on the page `{{::bindOnce}}`

Comment: Hi, I can't get the <thead> and <tr> to work properly with ng-table.  Actually, it works on the simulations I run at home, but not at work. At home, the way they configure the web platform prevents me to do what I want. I'm trying to use ng-table only because of the pagination feature. I was told I should use this framework on bootstrap 3. Could I use another table framework that provides a good pagination feature and have full control of the headers? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  I'll try to show a little basic paging thing that you could expand on to dynamically populate with your data, long story short is you can use the limitTo filter to implement the paging itself pretty easily and then just do the table as a regular table with ng-repeat https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: I put a semi-complete answer below with a custom directive for doing the pagination.  If you want something more thoroughly tested and probably more feature rich can check out ui-bootstrap as well https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#pagination

Comment: no problem if the post below fully answers the question please mark it as accepted if not let me know what's still broken but I think I got it to basically work as one would expect, I defined the "PaginationModel" but it's not actually being used here but that's just to show you could inject that service in the directive and in the controller somewhere to communicate the "startAt" which is really the important thing the paginator is determining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function(PaginationModel, DataService){
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.DataService = DataService;
    ctrl.maxPageButtons = 5;
    ctrl.abFilter = function(value, index, array) {
      if(!ctrl.abSearch)
        return true;
      return value.a == ctrl.abSearch || value.b == ctrl.abSearch;
    };
  })
  
  .service('DataService', function(){
    var dataService = { data: [] };
    
    for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
      var randA = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
      var randB = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
      var randC = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
      dataService.data.push({pos:i, a:randA,b:randB,c:randC});
    }
    
    return dataService; 
  })
  
  .directive('pagingDisplay', function(){
    return {
      scope:{
        startAt: '=',       //Two way binding for which element to start at
        numPerPage: '@',    //Number of elements we want per page
        totalElements: '@',  //Total number of elements in the collection
        maxButtons:'@'      //Maximum number of page number buttons to show
      },
      templateUrl:'templateId.html',
      link:function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
        //Computed when the num per page and total are provided
        var _totalPages = 0;  
        
        //Max page buttons to show (default 5)
        var _maxPages = 5;
        scope.model = {
          selectedPage: 0,
          showForward:false,
          showBackward:true
         };
        
        /**
        * Uses the current selected page, num pages, and max pages to
        * create an array that corresponds to the page numbers shown
        */
        function genPagesArray(numPages){
          scope.pages = [];
          
          if(numPages<=_maxPages)
          {
            for(var i=0; i<numPages; i++){
              scope.pages.push(i);
            }
          }
          else {
            var showEndPage = true, showStartPage = true;
            var halfPages = Math.floor((_maxPages-1)/2);
            
            var firstPage = Math.max(0, scope.model.selectedPage-halfPages);
            var lastPage = firstPage+_maxPages;
            
            if(lastPage > _totalPages)
            {
            
              firstPage += (_totalPages - lastPage);
              lastPage = _totalPages;
            }
            
            for(var i=firstPage, x=0; i<lastPage && x<_maxPages; x++, i++){
              scope.pages.push(i)
              
              if(i==numPages-1)
                showEndPage = false;
              if(i==0)
                showStartPage = false;
            }
            
            if(showEndPage)
            {
              scope.pages.pop();
              scope.pages.push(numPages-1);
            }
            if(showStartPage)
            {
              scope.pages.shift();
              scope.pages.unshift(0);
            }
          }
        }
        genPagesArray(5);
        
        scope.$watch('totalElements', function(newVal){
          var intVal = scope.totalElements;
          if(intVal && !isNaN(intVal = parseInt(intVal))){
            _totalPages = Math.ceil(intVal / scope.numPerPage)
            if(scope.model.selectedPage > _totalPages)
            {
              scope.firstPage();
            }
            else{
              genPagesArray(_totalPages);
            }
          }
        });
        
        scope.$watch('maxButtons', function(newVal){
          var intVal = scope.maxButtons;
          if(intVal && !isNaN(intVal = parseInt(intVal))){
            _maxPages = intVal;
            genPagesArray(_totalPages);
          }
        });
        
        scope.prevPage = function(){
          if(scope.model.selectedPage>0)
            scope.changeSelectedPage(scope.model.selectedPage-1)
        }
        scope.nextPage = function(){
          if(scope.model.selectedPage<_totalPages-1)
            scope.changeSelectedPage(scope.model.selectedPage+1)
        }
        scope.lastPage = function(){
          scope.changeSelectedPage(_totalPages-1)
        }
        scope.firstPage = function(){
          scope.changeSelectedPage(0)
        }
        
        scope.changeSelectedPage = function(pageToSelect){
          scope.model.selectedPage = pageToSelect;
          scope.startAt = pageToSelect*parseInt(scope.numPerPage);
          genPagesArray(_totalPages)
        }
      }
    }
  })
  
  .service('PaginationModel', function(){
    var serv = { curPage: 0, numPage: NaN};
    return serv;
  })
  ;
```

```css
.pagination-button{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  
  margin-right:2px;
  
  
  /* Disable Text Selection */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

.pagination-button:hover{
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.pagination-button:active, .pagination-button.selected{
  background-color: #ccffaa;
}

table{
  width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
<div>
  <span class="pagination-button" ng-click="firstPage()"> |< </span><span class="pagination-button" ng-click="prevPage()"> << </span><span class="pagination-button" 
    ng-click="changeSelectedPage(page)" 
    ng-class="{'selected':model.selectedPage == page}" 
    ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
    {{(page+1)}}
  </span><span class="pagination-button" ng-click="nextPage()"> >> </span><span class="pagination-button" ng-click="lastPage()"> >| </span>
</div>
</script>

<body>

<div>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as myctrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>#</td>
          <td colspan="2">a and b <input type="text" ng-model="myctrl.abSearch"/></td>
          <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>#</td>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="datum in myctrl.filtered = (myctrl.DataService.data | filter:myctrl.abFilter) | limitTo: 5 : myctrl.startAt">
          <td>{{::datum.pos}}</td>
          <td>{{::datum.a}}</td>
          <td>{{::datum.b}}</td>
          <td>{{::datum.c}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <paging-display num-per-page="5" max-buttons="{{myctrl.maxPageButtons}}" total-elements="{{myctrl.filtered.length}}" start-at="myctrl.startAt">
    </paging-display>
    
    <h1>Buttons to show</h1>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="100" ng-model="myctrl.maxPageButtons"/>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```